# Why did the show's producers choose to base their Klingons on Americans?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, star-trek-discovery

According to the "after-show" of Star Trek: Discovery, the Klingons are based on Americans. Can someone please explain how the producers aimed to make the comparison clear, or what similarities there are between Americans and Klingons? Having seen both episodes it was unclear in what respect the producers aimed to draw the comparison.

Comment: Whether Americans seem like Klingons or not sounds too opinion-based. Perhaps you could rephrase your question as, "Are the Klingons in Star Trek Discovery based on Americans?"

Comment: Not a Opinion but in fact stated on the Star Trek After Show.

Comment: I imagine you're getting downvotes because, as I said, "in what ways are Americans like Klingons?" is too opinion-based. If you asked, "Why did the show's producers choose to base their Klingons on Americans?", that would be an answerable question.

Comment: I've tried to edit your question by making it slightly clearer and less of a rant. You should take the advice given to you and not just deny or reject it. If my edits have changed your question feel free to roll them back.

Comment: I thought I asked pretty clearly my question but I like the edited way better as it does indeed convey my question a lot better.

Comment: A quote from the after-show would make this question even better.

Comment: It wouldn’t be the first time. Apparently the Ferengi were meant to symbolize modern-day (American) humans: greedy, misogynists, etc., in contrast to the utopian Federation.

Answer (score 8):

They aren't meant to represent Americans in general but are influenced by a certain political type of American: the ones who feel their "traditional American values" and lifestyles are under siege, that they're opposed by forces that want to make them less than they were, that are pining for the good old days when they were clearly the ones on top and no weird-looking and talking foreigner was going to tell them what to do.

And here's T'Kuvma, a populist who want to Make Klingons Great Again.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. Unless the after show specifically explains the claim then all we have are speculations and I don't see how this one is any less valid than whatever other traits others will identify. My opinion was that Americans have insane beliefs, just like these radical klingons, they have some kind of self defined sense of honor that doesn't appear to be honorable to anyone else, they will kill themselves in many ways just to prove a point or gain an advantage, etc. the list could go on. To be fair, I could draw similar parallels to just about any country

Comment: @KaiQing - actually, there are some quotes from the producers that hint that their political and social views and opinions heavily influenced the script. I'll try to find it, but in the meantime +1 to the answer. It is to the point, but I would phrase it differently. And as for insane beliefs - my opinion is that "The New Klingons" represent the part of American society the leftist producers (no point watering down terms after their first punch) simply do not understand. I for certain, being a foreigner from East Europe, identify with those insane beliefs over a whole swath of others.